# What does this mean in vectors in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<int> v[1000];
```

Is this for reserving space for the vector? But isn't the command for reserving space `()`? What does this do?

Comment: Its an array of 1000 (default constructed) vectors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is an array, with each element being a vector, so there are 1000 default-constructed (empty) vectors.

However, if you wanted to make a single vector of 1000 `int`, you would say

```
vector<int> v(1000);
```

Comment: And what will this mean, `vector<int> graph[102][102]`. A 2-D matrix of vectors, is it?

Comment: @JohnLui Yes exactly.